# List of deleted records in openerp

Tags: odoo

Is there any way to get the **list of deleted records** in OpenERP? I have heard that openerp records the deleted record list.. but i don't know where to browse for it..

I'm trying to synchronize two databases. So I hardly require the deleted record's model name and id so that i can delete the corresponding record from the other database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make something like a **replication_automated_rule** based on the **base_action_rule** model. Look for the code at **addons/base_action_rule/base_action_rule.py**.

An **action rule** links **server actions** to objects (of a given model) that accomplish a given condition (defined by filters). Action rules are very easy to use, even on the administrative interface.

The objects are checked on **creation** and **update** but you can inherit from **base_action_rule** and define the check on **delete** also. It works by mean of creating  custom wrappers to the **create** and **write** methods for the memory representation of the model object over it is told to work. You would need to add an **_wrap_unlink** method based on **_wrap_create** and adds a line to **_register_hook**:

```
model_obj.unlink = self._wrap_unlink(model_obj.unlink, model)
```

The **wrapper** method inside **_wrap_create** and **_wrap_update** execute the hooks after execute its normal function. When you define the **wrapper** method inside your **_wrap_unlink**, you should be care of executing the hooks before the normal function of unlink, given that unlink erase the object and it would not be available for the hooks.

Also, you should define an **server action** which saves the necessary data for your replication queue or log.

Good luck !!

Comment: My answer was an old one for openerp v6.0.

Answer (score 1):

When you click Delete from UI in openerp you have access to ORM Menthod `UNLINK` prototype od method is :

```
def unlink(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None)
    """
    #Delete records with given ids
    Param cr:  database cursor
    Param uid: current user id
    Param ids: id or list of ids
    Param context:   (optional) context arguments, like lang, time zone
    Return : True
    Raise AccessError:
        if user has no unlink rights on the requested object
        if user tries to bypass access rules for unlink on the requested object
    Raise UserError:

        if the record is default property for other records
    """
```

Here Ids contains the list of ids to be unlinked so before deleting you can play with them.

But If record are once deleted from OpenERP, you can not have access as they are no more in db.

Optional, mechanism here can be useful is `active` field. Active field in OE is special field if you define active Boolean field on your model then if any record set to active false, yo can not see that record on view without special efforts, But Tricky part is you still have those record on table with active=False so you can access them very easily using domain.

Comment: Hi jam, Thank you for your reply. I'm trying to synchronize two databases. So I hardly require the deleted record's model name and id so that i can delete the corresponding record from the other database

Comment: Weel in that case you can use ID field, match Id of both db unique ids are missing ids,

Comment: Thats little bit difficult.. because sometime we have to sync 5-10 models, and these records may contain thousands of records.. so searching for each record is time consuming

Comment: yupo that is little bit difficult but, yes you can always write some impressiveness python script to the Job, Which will fully automatwe the job;.

Answer (score 0):

I think [jam's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10975584/4794) is that you override the `unlink()` method on any models you want to replicate, and log the deleted ids into a separate table. Then your synchronization process can read and purge that table.

You might also look into [replication tools at the database level](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling) if you just want to duplicate the entire database.

Comment: Thank you Don for your reply. But I got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

I inherited the class **object_proxy** from osv.osv and inside this there is a function named **execute**,`def execute(self, db, uid, model, method, *args, **kw):` I just override this function, if the method is unlink then i saved that record_id and model name to a new table in the database