# In Odoo v8, how can I have a function called when a record is created in a given table?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to automatically create a contract, whenever some product is sold. I added a field to the product, pointing to a template contract.

I know about @api.depends, but that relies on creating a field.function. I don't need a field, but still want my function called. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override write method of the product and inside you can call your function like this,

```
def write(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
    # add your custom code here
    return super(class_name,self).write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context=context)
```

You need to check your field in vals, your field (I think state field) will available if the value of this field has been changed, check as follow.

```
if vals.get('state',False):
   ## call your function
```

Remember you will get only those fields inside vals which are updated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this indeed answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also give a look to the [auditlog](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/auditlog/)  module code from OCA, they have implemented an action to log the records...

But if you want to make it flexible, customizable and avoid hardcoding you better use [action rules](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/online/base_action_rule/) ...

Action rules allow you to bind actions to object creation and update. If you want to hook other methods here is [a possible approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974779/list-of-deleted-records-in-openerp/) proposed to a similar problem (log deletes):